# Converting fragment shader into compute shader

Tags: compute-shader

I'm learning compute shaders after several years of experience with fragment and vertex shaders. I'd like to convert the algorithms from one of my procedural fragment shaders into a compute shader that uses the same algorithms but outputs the resulting procedural map to a texture and sends it to the CPU. Does anyone know of a tutorial or sample code that will point me in the right direction? I just need a generic framework.